# Pushing Google Analytics Goals Manually for Specific Variation

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I have a question about Google Analytics Content Experiments.

My goal type is currently URL Destination.
And we push conversions manually to Analytics after phone call matching, normally it takes one day.

We use this code for pushing conversions.

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]); 
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/call/conv ']);
```

What I want to know is how do I push a conversion manually for a specific variation.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

In GA Content Experiments each variation has it's own url, so you'd simply use the fitting url as the second parameter to _trackPageview:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/call/VARIATION']);
```

regards,

Eike

Comment: Can you tell me how do I bind conversion to a variation?

I have created 4 Variations and 4 Goals, Now what?